# How to use PooledDbContextFactory without DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

We are updating an application to ASPNET .NET 6 and EF Core 6. The application started without DI. Currently, we are creating a `new DBContext ()` for each query. We want to switch to inject the DBContext, however for all current code we want to use [PooledDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=without-di%2Cwith-constant) to avoid creating the context on every query.

We would like to know how this implementation should be in an ASPNET application. We are testing by saving the pool to a `ThreadLocal <PooledDbContextFactory <DBContext>>` object to reuse the pool. Also we have test with a `private static readonly Lazy<PooledDbContextFactory<DBEntities>>` object.

This is a correct way? Should or can it be done in another way? Is this use correct?

Comment: `ThreadLocal` means that every thread should have it's own pool (I would say that this is not what you actually want). `Lazy` means that pool instantiation will be lazy (i.e. at first call to `Lazy`).

Comment: The reason for using ThreadLocal is that I am not sure if it is correct to share a static `PooledDbContextFactory` variable in the whole application. Should I use as `static readOnly PooledDbContextFactory<DBCOntext>`?